# Closing duplicates in review queue works only if original question is shown

Tags: bug

When reviewing a duplicate question in the close queue, clicking on "Close" only works when the original question is shown. It does not work when the duplicate is shown.

[image]

Can this please be fixed so the button works in both cases?

PS: Noticed in Safari and Firefox

Comment: See [In the close vote review queue, when you switch to look at a duplicate question, the close button is broken](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/352961/295232) – SE is currently working on some major improvements to the review queues. Let's hope they fix this as well.

Comment: @Glorfindel Ah, somebody did dig deeper than I did when posting this to MSE :-) Let's see what the future brings then.